# How can I make grooves deeper on a scanned 3d model?

Tags: sculpting, 3d-printing

I have an 3d Scanned Object and I want to print it out but the grooves are too small for the 3d printer how can I make them deeper without having to sculpt every groove by myself?
The mesh is a chaos i just important the file directly from the photoscan software and that's about it. Please help me...

[image]

Comment: I would suggest you to retopo the photoscan or to model it from scratch. Then  you could test various procedural displacement textures and when satisfied with the results, convert displacement texture to actual mesh displacement using this https://youtu.be/McALCOr39rY

Comment: hello there
thank you very much but the problem is the client wants the exact same grooves as seen on the sculpture